# How do I take a Screenshot of the new "Touch Bar" on the newer Macs?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-capture, touch-bar

I am using Safari on the MacBook Pro, and had about 100 tabs open. As a result the Touch Bar lit up with lots of tiny images of the pages I opened.

I wanted to show someone how the Touch Bar had changed, but didn't want to take out my phone and take a picture of it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has released an update to the *Grab* application that allows you to capture the Touch Bar.

[image]

The Touch Bar is constantly dynamic in nature, so Apple added a "timed" capture for the Touch Bar so you can navigate to the App with the Touch Bar layout before the "grab" executes.

You can find the *Grab* application under Utilities.  <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and select *Grab* or use Spotlight (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) and just start typing "grab..."